# Stars and Bars Combinatorics Variation - Partial Derivatives

Tags: combinatorics

In another Stackexchange question the question

> How many distinct partials of order $k$ for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

has been answered with
$$\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$$
and with the comment that this is a balls and stars argument. My question is if someone can explain the derivation of this, not necessarily with the Balls and Stars Argument but it would be helpful? Thanks in advance!

> Note: It is important to say, that after equality of mixed partials, some partial derivatives cancel out!

Comment: The connection with Stars and Bars is:  a partial of order $k$ is determined uniquely by an $n-$tuple $(a_1,\cdots, a_n)$ of non-negative integers such that $\sum a_i=k$.  The associated partial is, of course, $\frac {\partial^{a_1}}{\partial x_1^{a_1}}\cdots \frac {\partial^{a_n}}{\partial x_n^{a_n}}$

Comment: @lulu But if i derive with respect to $x_1$, then to $x_2$, thats the same as the other way around but adding them both gives 3 so they would count uniquely by your logic.

Comment: I don't understand.  Since the various operators commute, we can always write them uniquely in the form I mentioned.  If $(n,k)=(2,2)$, I count the operator $\frac {\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac {\partial}{\partial x_2}$ exactly once, as the $2-$tuple $(1,1)$.  The other $2-$tuples are $(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$ and these correspond to the two "pure" second derivatives.

Comment: @lulu I was just too dumb to get your argument. Thanks for your help, I got it now!

Comment: No worries.  Glad to have helped.

Comment: @lulu I have another question: What if the functions are 0 if I derive $k$ times. Then the whole thing gets way more complicated doesnt ist?

Comment: The question only concerned the operators, not the result they give on any particular function.  If you specify a function then, sure, some of the operators might yield the same result.